# Command or script to delete all text in between two flags (html tags), in all files in a directory?

Tags: text-processing, html

I have a directory full of html files that all have certain tags that I want deleted. For instance, in all files I have `<p class="message"> </p>` that I want gone, but the text inside the tags is different in each file.

For cases where the text in each file is the same I have been using

```shell
find . -type f -name '*.html' -exec sed -i'' -e 's/existing/replacement/g' {} +
```

to replace the old text with the new. However in the example above, the different text in between the tags means that won't work.

Is there a similar command or tool available that would allow me to delete or replace everything between two specified strings?

Comment: Delete the text ___in-between___ specified tags, or delete specified tags ___and___ the variable text inside? Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Personally, I hate getting the ole' "look at this" as an answer.  However, in this case, a different thread explains this exact procedure well.

[using-sed-to-delete-all-lines-between-two-matching-patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287755/using-sed-to-delete-all-lines-between-two-matching-patterns)

Answer (score 2):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my regex L { "<p class=\"message\">" };                  \          
            my regex R { "</p>" };                                   \                               \
            my $dest-dir = "/path/to/destination/dir/";              \
            for dir() -> $file {                                     \
              with $file.slurp { / <L> .*? <R> /                     \
                ?? my $new-file = .subst( :g, / <L> <(.*?)> <R> / )  \
                !! next;                                             \
              spurt("$dest-dir" ~ "$file".IO, $new-file)             \
              }                                                      \
            };'
```

Raku is a programming language in the Perl-family of programming languages. Briefly, both `L`-and-`R` regexes are declared and assigned a value. A `$dest-dir` scalar is declared and assigned a string. The current `dir()` is iterated through with `for`, and each `$file` .IO object is analyzed/modified in the following block.

Within the outer block, the `$file` is `slurp`ed (read all at once), in an inner block this text is immediately tested for the presence of the regexes, with the `.*?` "any-character-zero-or-more-times,taken-frugally" regex in-between. Note the `L`-and-`R` regexes here must be interpolated with angle brackets, i.e. `<L>`-and-`<R>`, because they are within the `/ ... /` matcher),

Within the inner block Raku's ternary operator  **Test** `??` **True** `!!` **False**  is used. If the 3 regexes in series are  found the central "atom" `<(.*?)>` is now wrapped with `<(`...`)>` capture-markers, indicating that the external matches are to be dropped and only the `.*?` deleted (`subst` with nothing). A `$new-file` is created with these inner characters deleted. If the regex is not found, the block skips ahead to the `next` file (exiting the inner block). This allows the newly-created `$new-file` to be written out (`spurt`ed) to the correct directory, with the original `$file` name.

Sample Input (in original `dir/file`):

```
first line
<p class="message"> foo </p>
<p class="message"> bar </p>
<p class="message">
          baz
  </p>

last line
```

Sample Output (written to new `dir/file`)

```
first line
<p class="message"></p>
<p class="message"></p>
<p class="message"></p>

last line
```

Above, the "Sample Output" shows three instances of the inner text of specified html tags being deleted, even if the opening/closing tags are on different lines. In order to substitute with new (literal string) text instead, change the following segment of code.

*From:*
`.subst( :g, / <L> <(.*?)> <R> / )`

*To:*
`.subst( :g, / <L> <(.*?)> <R> /, "new-text" )`

---

https://docs.raku.org/routine/dir
https://docs.raku.org/type/Regex
https://raku.org

Answer (score 2):

HTML tags can usually span several lines, or there could be more than one per line, so you could use `perl`'s slurp mode where the full contents of files are processed as a whole, and its `*?` non-greedy version of `*` to match as little as possible between the opening and closing tags.

The `-i` options is also non-standard, those that support it have actually copied from `perl` though with variations when not using a backup suffix (`-i` vs `-i ''`).

```
find . -name '*.html' -type f -exec perl -0777 -pi -e '
  s{<p class="message">.*?</p>}{ }gs' {} +
```